# Making a method to find lower case letters in a string

Tags: java, methods, boolean

```
public static boolean hasLower ( String text){
char c;

System.out.println( "Enter Text Here: : ");
c = scan.nextChar();

   for ( int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++){
     c = text.charAt(i);
      if ( c <= 97 && c >= 122) {
         return true;

        }//end if
       }//end for
   return false;

}//end hasLowers
```

> I have this, but i trying to figure out how  to do it without ASCII
>   Then im printing it from an another file, this is what i have
>
> > This is supposed to print out lower case of the string used which is text. I tried using a boolean method to figure out if it was true or
> >     false.
>
> ```
>       Lab7Methods.hasLower ( text );
>        System.out.println();
> ```

Comment: `c` cannot be <= 97 AND >= 122. This will always return false.

Answer (score 1):

Your `hasLower` method should be testing the characters passed in `text` (not reading more user input). Also, your logic appears to be incorrect because you want values in the range of lower case a and lower case z. Finally, a character constant is written in single quotes (`'a'` and `'z'`). Like,

```
public static boolean hasLower(String text) {
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        char c = text.charAt(i);
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```